# Term describing the "in good standing" conditional

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

As I understand it, the phrase "in good standing" describes a person or entity having complied with all their explicit obligations and therefore has no negative history so far. Being "in good standing" or having "lost good standing" are the two possible conditions, what is the umbrella term that would describe these?

I need to use this in a text-based layout:

**Feedback**
This person is in good standing.

--or--

**Feedback**
This person has lost good standing.

My question is, what is the best term to use in place of "Feedback" in the heading in the above two examples?

Comment: **Standing** [n the community]? This could make sense, depending on the context and the preceding and subsequent headings.

Comment: Could the word **reputation** fit?

Comment: @CowperKettle **reputation**, that's brilliant!

Comment: What is the umbrella term that covers "in good standing", and "lost good standing"? I should have thought the answer was fairly clear - namely ***standing***.

Comment: Stick with simple "standing" as Livrecache and WS2 suggest… and in my book, "good standing" is like "good" itself: always more than neutral and never in any way negative, not even in the sense of  of "has no negative history so far"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In computing we typically use the word status. It is noteworthy that being in good standing may be a state which does not indicate a perfect history, but sometimes only indicates a time period or other details.

> sta·tus /ˈstādəs,ˈstadəs/ noun
>
> 1. the relative social, professional, or other standing of someone or something.
>
> "an improvement in the status of women"
>
> synonyms: standing, rank, ranking, position, social position, level, place, estimation; datedstation
>
> "the status of women"
>
> 2. the position of affairs at a particular time, especially in political or commercial contexts.
>
> "an update on the status of the bill"
>
> synonyms: state, position, condition, shape, stage
>
> "the current status of the project"

Source: Google Dictionary
https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/licensing/google